# Linear programming

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, linear-programming

How to implement the incremental linear programming algorithm for 2-Dimension?

I am looking for implementation details of incremental algorithm of linear programming in 2-D. I am trying to work on red-blue point separation.

Comment: Do you search Seidel's Algorithm for LP? It is incremental and randomized algorithm for LP, that works very well for small dimensions.

Comment: The textbook 'Combinatorial Optimization' (http://www.amazon.com/Combinatorial-Optimization-Algorithms-Complexity-Computer/dp/0486402584) by Papadimitriou et al. deals with the basic simplex algorithm in detail.